# Using observable in template freezes browser

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

Using `auth.appUser$` in component.html causes the browser to freeze. However, subscribing to `auth.appUser$` in component.ts correctly outputs the information to the console.

Note that appUser$ has type: `Observable<AppUser>`, where AppUser was defined in an interface with the fields name, email, and isAdmin.

The console does not output any exceptions.

navbar.component.html: (the browser freezes here!)

```
<li *ngIf="auth.appUser$ | async as user; else anonymousUser" ngbDropdown class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a ngbDropdownToggle class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      {{ user.name }}
    </a>
</li>
```

navbar.component.ts: (the browser does not freeze!)

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public auth: AuthService) {
        this.auth.appUser$.subscribe(user => console.log(user.name));
    }
}
```

`auth.appUser$` is an observable defined in auth.service.ts:

```
export class AuthService {

  user$: Observable<firebase.User>;

constructor(
    private userService: UserService) {
    this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState;
  }

get appUser$(): Observable<AppUser> {
    return this.user$
      .pipe(
        switchMap(user => this.userService.get(user.uid).valueChanges())
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Feel free to provide a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com !

Answer (score 1):

Please try to warp the async in braces

```
*ngIf="(auth.appUser$ | async) as user; else anonymousUser"
```

Alternative

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(auth.appUser$ | async) as user; else anonymousUser">
  <li> content... </li>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Please try with `ng-container` without any bootstrap directives like this `<ng-container *ngIf="(auth.appUser$ | async) as user; else anonymousUser">Your `li` tag goes here</ng-container>`

Comment: Will you please update `navbar.component.html` full data?

Comment: i mean full template data. Make sure no other angular directives affected this (like ngFor)